# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ExponentFacebook.default.initializeAsync')

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, facebook-authentication

I am trying to use Facebook Auth for my firebase react native project and I am running into this TypeError at the InitalizeAsync method.

```
import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';

export const loginWithFacebook = async () => {
  await Facebook.initializeAsync('ID_OF_APP');
  const {type, token}: any = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({
    permissions: ['public_profile', 'email'],
  });
```

I've been trying to troubleshoot this for the last day or so.

ID_OF_APP is only in the question...not my actual code (for the sake of making this question easier to understand to future viewers).

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
import { AccessToken, LoginManager } from "react-native-fbsdk"

        state = {
                email: '',
                sso_token: '',
                sso_uid: '',
                loading: false,
            }    

initUser(token) {
    axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=email,name,friends&access_token=${token}`,
        responseType: 'json'
    }).then((response) => {

        const { data } = response

        const { first_name, last_name } = this.split_name(data.name)

        this.setState(
            { sso_token: token, sso_uid: data.id, email: data.email, first_name, last_name },
        )
    }).catch((err) => { console.warn(err) })
}

 onFBSignin() {
    this.setState({ loading: true })

    LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(["email", "public_profile"])
        .then(result => {
            if (result.isCancelled) {
                this.setState({ loading: false })
            }
            else {
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
                    .then((data) => {
                        const { accessToken } = data
                        this.initUser(accessToken)
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.warn(error)
                    })
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.warn(error)
            this.setState({ loading: false })
        }
```

Comment: I did do that... I just reverted it back in the question.

Comment: Updated the answer try it and let me know @BestFromAbove

Comment: which library are you using for Facebook? The only login method I have is logInWithPermissionsAsync.

Comment: I am using react-native-fbsdk, however you can replace my loginWithPermissions to logInWithReadPermissionsAsync

Comment: Alright I changed to react-native-fbsdk and am using the example given by their docs, however im still getting the same error for LoginManager.logInWithPermissions ----> (TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'LoginManager.logInWithPermissions'))

Comment: @BestFromAbove I have updated my code accordingly. Try it once again